# Search box to find user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm somewhat new to rails. I'm going through making the classic twitter clone right now. I want to have a search bar on my homepage that allows the user to search for a twitter handle, and if the handle exists, it will send the user to the show page for that twitter handle.

I've been following a RailsCast on how to implement a simple search, but instead of doing it on the index like the video, I want to do it on the show action. I've run into some problems though. The form sits on my user index view.
Here is the error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Users#index
Showing c:/Sites/Projects/twitterapp/twitter/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_tag(user_path, method: 'get') do %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search]) %>
      <%= submit_tag("Search", name: nil) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my show action:

```
def show
        @user = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

And here is my search method in my user model:

```
def self.search(search)
        if search
            find(:all, conditions:['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot use the `show` method as a search result finder. Because according to the rails convention:
For any `resource` like `users`, rails scaffold generates **index**,**new**, **show**, **create**, **update**, **delete** methods based on your routes files.

Thus based on the conventional way, `show` method always asks for an `object`. Lets say you are using `UserContoller` show  method. It asks for a `user` object. Which you haven't provide in the form. that's why `:id` missing error is given.

I would tell you to do some more learning. And for searching create a different method in a different controller and define that controller method to the `routes.rb` file. This is the best way to do.
If you still want to use the `show` method, then change the `show` methods routing from the `routes.rb` file. You've to manually declare the show action on routes file.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `user_path` and path need to inform id from present user

you can do this in action :index but I recommend you to create a action to this

***view***

```
<%= form_tag(search_users_path, method: 'get') do %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search]) %>
      <%= submit_tag("Search", name: nil) %>
<% end %>
```

***routes.rb***

```
resources :users do
  post 'search',  :on => :collection
end
```

***users_controller.rb***

```
def search
  @user = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

You should to create a view `search.html.erb` similar as `index.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

As Emu and Breno pointed what causing the problem `user_path` requires an user `id`

**Solution idea:**
Why not just point to users index action? like this:

```
<%= form_tag(users_path, method: 'get') do %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search]) %>
      <%= submit_tag("Search", name: nil) %>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
def index
   if params[:search]
      @user = User.search(params[:search])
   end
end
```

and you can use `ajax` `remote: true` to handle the returned user object

Answer (score 0):

Found your question via Google, but the responses and suggestions didn't work for me. Found another solution that did, so seems worth posting here.

"Search and Filter Rails Models Without Bloating Your Controller":
http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/